# Error when declaring Button Click - Android C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, error-handling, click

I am trying to declare an `ImageButton` for a Click Event, but an Error is given.
What would be giving this error?

(Error is occuring on `btnSettingsBack.Click += btnSettingsBack_Click;`

MainActivity Code (OnCreate):

```
    ImageButton btnSettings = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.btnSettings);
    ImageButton btnSettingsBack = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.btnSettingsBack);
    btnAdd = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnAdd);
    lvNotes = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lvNotes);
   dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);

    //Load Data
    LoadNoteList();

    btnAdd.Click += BtnAdd_Click;

    btnSettings.Click += BtnSettings_Click;

    btnSettingsBack.Click += BtnSettingsBack_Click;

}
```

Error:

[image: Error Image]

**UPDATE 1:** ***Settings.axml Layout Code:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:padding="20px"
        android:background="#22A7F0">
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/menu_back"
            android:background="#22A7F0"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="30px"
            android:id="@+id/btnSettingsBack"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

**UPDATE 2:** ***OnCreate Code***

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            ActionBar.Hide();



            ImageButton btnSettings = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.btnSettings);
            ImageButton btnSettingsBack = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.btnSettingsBack);
            btnAdd = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnAdd);
            lvNotes = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lvNotes);
           dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);

            //Load Data
            LoadNoteList();

            btnAdd.Click += BtnAdd_Click;

            btnSettings.Click += BtnSettings_Click;

            btnSettingsBack.Click += BtnSettingsBack_Click;

        }
```

Comment: Make sure `btnSettingsBack` exists in the Layout and that is declared as `ImageButton`.

Comment: It is inside my axml layout and declared as ImageButton, see update 1

Comment: Update with you full OnCreate method

Comment: OnCreate code in Update 2, although i dont think it will make a difference to the first code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting as the contentView of your activity a file called **Main.axml**

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
```

But you have the `ImageButton` defined in another file called **Settings.axml**

This is why is `btnSettingsBack` is null and hence the error.

Each one of these Controls must exists in the Layout you set as the ContentView of your page. If any of those are not present you will have a NullReferenceException when trying to access it.

```
ImageButton btnSettings = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.btnSettings);
ImageButton btnSettingsBack = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.btnSettingsBack);
btnAdd = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnAdd);
```

Think of `FindViewById` as a way of querying the Layout you provided to your Activity using the ResourceId you are passing. If the Id is not present this method will not complaint but it will return Null so it's our job making sure every Id you pass is part of the layout you are setting.

Comment: So how would I define the ImageButton and declare a click event from the MainActivity ?

Comment: Copy the code you defined in the `Settings.axml` file regarding the `ImageButton` with id `btnSettingsBack`

Comment: That is in the question, labelled Settings.axml code above

Comment: You cannot access nor define a click event to an object/control in another layout other than your current layout. This said from the Activity which Layout is Main.axml you cannot access the ImageButton `btnSettingsBack` located in the Settings.axml

Comment: So then how would I use that `ImageButton` click event?

Comment: It is ok, thank you for the help! I have found an Xamarin thread that I can understand better.
I will up vote and mark!